# Reading MySQL via Python sometimes causes warning 1292, seemingly interpreting seconds as greater than 60.

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.5, pymysql

This is a strange one, and though I find several posts dealing with the 1292 Warning, nothing seems to quite fit my scenario.

**Setup:** 
Python 3.5
PyMySQL==0.7.11
MySql 5.5.53

**Query:**

```
Executing sql: SELECT PacketID, `Type`, `Length`, Raw_Data
                    FROM extra_packets 
                    WHERE `Time` > NOW() - 10  AND PacketId > '18345' ORDER BY `Time` DESC;
```

**Result:**

```
python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:323: Warning: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '20171107190398' for column 'Time' at row 1")
```

**Sample Data:**

```
PacketID    Time                Type    Length  Raw_Data

18,346      2017-11-07 19:04:06 76  22  .......
18,345      2017-11-07 19:04:01 76  22  .......
18,344      2017-11-07 19:03:57 76  22  .......
```

**Notes:**

- In the warning message, the seconds value is greater than 60 - I assume this is the problem?
- This doesn't always happen, presumably it is time specific
- I'm not actually using `Time` in the response -- just for the filter.

**Question:** (Obviously) How do I correct this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper `INTERVAL` expression instead of `10`.

```
WHERE Time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 SECOND)
```

Your code is converting `NOW()` to an integer like `20171107190408` and then subtracting `10` from that. You'll get the error whenver the seconds of the current time are less than `10`.